# Unable to connect after ODOO 9 configuration

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I am stucked while configuring ODOO 9. i have followed [this](http://openies.com/blog/install-openerp-odoo-9-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/) link to get ODOO 9 run. All steps executed successfully and when i try to run this command "**sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start**" it returns Ok message but when i try to access localhost:8069 from browser it says "**unable to connect**". Please help and suggest the solutions. Thanks in advance.

I am using Ubuntu **14.04**

Comment: See the log file for error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer nightly odoo link 
https://nightly.odoo.com/

This link Provide you latest setup and how to install a odoo in your pc

This all type of setup available  in .exe , .deb, .tar

This link is useful to you for setup a odoo